# Remote mySql with a dynamic IP address

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a python script on my PC that needs to run every day as my host provider does not support the python modules im using.

The python script collects data and then feeds it to the mySql database online. The issue I am having is that with remote mySql I need to add my IP address to allow remote access whenever my IP address changes.

Is there another way of doing this without doing all the extra manual work of updating my IP every other day?

Answer (score 2):

Best to not expose the actual database over the network at all. Instead split the database-related code into a second script and create yourself a "data upload API":

- Script 1 runs on local machine, collects data and uploads it via HTTPS POST.
- Script 2 runs as a webapp on the server, receives the HTTPS POST upload and inserts data into the SQL database.

But if you don't want to do that, an alternative might be SSH tunnelling. Look into whether your server accepts SSH connections using the `-L` option, and if so, use it to tunnel port 3306 (the MySQL port).

(Based on the module comment, I'm assuming the server is part of a web hosting system and does not give its users full root privileges, so the third option – a full VPN – is probably not possible to implement.)